# Android Studio: Working with parameters

Tags: java, android, url, parameters, parameter-passing

Could someone explain to me how parameters work in java? I am using 
Android Studio and would like to know if I am trying to get params from a url connection should I use this (my code):

```
            params.put("Pass", password);

            params.put("Username", email);
```

"Pass" is where the user passwords are stored on my online database.
"Username" is where the user emails are stored on my online database.

Comment: I hope that password isn't plaintext!

Comment: the password has letters and numbers @dahui

Comment: No I mean the password should be hashed and salted, if you don't know what that means you should read up on it if you are ever working with passwords in a commercial/public project.

Comment: What object is this params? Is it a bundle? And what exactly do you want to do with it?

Comment: RequestParams. I want the user to input a username (email) and password and have that username and password verified by the returned data from the server @abeikverdi

Answer (score 0):

As someone commented you should not send passwords in plain text to your server. Make sure to use a SSL/TLS (https) layer to protect your data.

Other than that you should be able to use that code.

Comment: The server is secure (https). Thanks. I am trying to validate the data being sent to the server. @JoakimEricsson